# prerender-spa-plugin not working on the server

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, url-routing, single-page-application

I'm trying to run build on the server. But with prerendering, the following error occurs. On desktop versions of ubuntu and macOS, there is no such problem, the problem is only server-side. I tried on different servers.

```
95% emittingError: Failed to launch chrome!                                               


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/phpuser/testPrerender/frontend/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:255:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/home/phpuser/testPrerender/frontend/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:245:60)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
[Prerenderer - PuppeteerRenderer] Unable to start Puppeteer
(node:2535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null
(node:2535) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My prerender-spa-plugin settings in webpack:

```
new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
    // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
    staticDir: _.outputPath,
    // Required - Routes to render.
    routes: ['/', '/abouts', '/mobile-apps', '/docs/service-fees', '/news', '/legal/Terms%20of%20use', '/legal/Refund%20policy', '/legal/Privacy%20Policy', '/legal/Notification%20o$
    renderer: new PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer({
      renderAfterDocumentEvent: 'render-event',
      headless: false,
    }),
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it works perfectly locally but issue come on the server. My temporal fix was to reduce the number of routes being passed on the

```
routes: []
```

Comment: That's really not a fix, the routes are absolute necessary in most cases, otherwise there is no point for prerender...

Comment: I said temporal fix because my project couldn't build for production

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is that `npm run build` succeeds locally, but fails when deployed to the server.
It is most likely related to the puppeteer used in prerender-spa-plugin 3.x. （Reference: [https://qiita.com/pokotyan/items/11806b8b77f4a3527951）](https://qiita.com/pokotyan/items/11806b8b77f4a3527951%EF%BC%89)
Because the configuration on the CI was not authorized to change, I discarded version 3.
Later I used v2.1.0 which based on the PhantomJS and deployed successfully on the server.

vue-cli3 & "prerender-spa-plugin": "^2.1.0"
vue.config.js

```
configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
        // Absolute path to compiled SPA
        path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        // List of routes to prerender
        ['/a', '/b', '/c', '/d', '/e'],
        {
          // options
          ignoreJSErrors: true,
        }
      )
    ],
}
```